Alex´s code for video presentation (2)
I still use the code presented by AlexG to present videos in slides prepared with beamer.
The code can be found here: Media9 is becoming obsolete Dec 2020. Any alternatives for embedding video/audio in LaTeX? and uses pdfbase package.
I am using Windows 10 and Adobe Reader.
Although I'm using the autoplay starred command on all slides, it works only in the first slide n which there is a video (mp4 file). For the others, I need to click to run the video. I would like to have all videos playing automatically. Any hint? I was not able to access the enablePlayerControls.reg file and do the following advised change:
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureState]
"HonorControls"=dword:00000001

Further, the above takes place only in the first time that I run the slide. From the second time on, all videos require a click to run.

As I understand it, some stuff which used to work in Adobe Reader just isn't an option any more due to changes to tighten security. It doesn't run on Linux, so I tend not to use this stuff (even though I mostly use Reader when actually showing the slides) because I can't test. But there was another post recently about something similar and, basically, the answer was: you can only get media playing outside the viewer. If you want integrated, switch to web-based presentations. However, I emphasise that I have no knowledge of this myself. I'm just reporting the verdict as I remember it.

@MarceloAlves Please choose a title which will help future users in a similar situation to find your question.
